# How to change Highcharts xAxis label color individually?

Tags: highcharts

I have been able to change the color of my charts xAxis labels by using the following:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    marginBottom: 80
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    labels: {
      style: {
        color: 'red'
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
  }]
});
```

Although, the above changes all xAxis labels to be red.

How can I change each labels color individually, so that "Jan" is red, "Feb" is blue, etc.

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/xqrvy9qm/)

Comment: If my solution solves your problem, don't forget to accept it ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use Axis.labels.formatter and return your label in html tag with style attribute, which can define your color.

```
const color = {
    Jan: 'red',
  Feb: 'green',
  Mar: 'blue'
}

const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    marginBottom: 80
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'],
    labels: {
      formatter () {
        return `<span style="color: ${color[this.value]}">${this.value}</span>`
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]
  }]
})


console.log(chart.series[0].data)
```

Live example:
http://jsfiddle.net/508jej83/

Comment: i tried with background-color, just not working

Answer (score 0):

I hope for you!!!

```
xAxis : {               
                categories : _category,
                labels : {
                    formatter : function() {
                        if (_category != null && _category.length > 0) {
                            var currentColumn = -1;
                            for (var i = 0; i < _category.length; i++) {
                                if (_category[i] == this.value) {
                                    currentColumn = i;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                            if (isNumberEven(currentColumn)) {                              
                                return '<span style="fill: blue;">' + this.value + '</span>';

                            } else {
                                return this.value;
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is the Highcharts [useHTML setting](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.useHTML). This works with highcharts export server. Encode the colors as html directly in the category labels:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
  marginBottom: 80
},
xAxis: {
   categories: ['<span style="color:green">Jan</span>', '<span style="color:blue">Feb</span>', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
   labels: {
      useHTML: true
      style: {
        color: 'red'
      }
    }
},
series: [{
  data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
}]
});
```